# User updating his own records , being able to comment on others records

Tags: java, struts2, spring-security, acl

I have a little confusion about a requirement. I wanted an experienced opinion.

I have a Spring Security , Struts 2 app. It is using different user roles for security like `ROLE_USER`, `ROLE_ADMIN`, and `ROLE_SUBADMIN`. Users and subadmins enter product information. I have a menu option User Profile where user's see their own records. `ROLE_USER` should be able to edit only his/her own products , while `ROLE_SUBADMIN` should be able to edit any product. Any user (`ROLE_USER` or `ROLE_SUBADMIN`) should be able to comment on any of the products.

What is the best way to achieve this?

1. Spring security ACL
2. Store user's ids in the DB with product info and then use search queries to display records and restrict user based on roles.

what is a common practice to handle such situations?

Thanks in advance for your expert comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already using Spring Security, the option 1) is better suited for this. If not using Spring Security then it out of topic of this question. You said you already using it. You still have to implement ACLs or choose other solutions that has already implemented it. But if your requirements don't increase while you implementing option 2) in which I very doubt, and the question itself is vague, then option 2) is faster and easy to implement.